# Qt - set QWidget with a QWidget class

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning to use Qt and I want to extend the Terminal Example of Qt. I want to use its console.cpp in a QWidget from de Containers tab in the Design editor.

In the Terminal Example of Qt, this class is used like this:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
console = new Console;
console->setEnabled(false);
setCentralWidget(console);
```

But as I want to use it in a smaller QWidget I don't know how to set it, which method can I use as equivalent of setCentralWidget for my QWidget? [Image of the Design tab with the widget I want to set to the QWidget class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf20G.png)

Can I also use the same QWidget in several tabs?

The console.cpp code is the following one.

```
#include "console.h"

#include <QScrollBar>

#include <QtCore/QDebug>

Console::Console(QWidget *parent)
    : QPlainTextEdit(parent)
    , localEchoEnabled(false)
{
    document()->setMaximumBlockCount(100);
    QPalette p = palette();
    p.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::black);
    p.setColor(QPalette::Text, Qt::green);
    setPalette(p);

}

void Console::putData(const QByteArray &data)
{
    insertPlainText(QString(data));

    QScrollBar *bar = verticalScrollBar();
    bar->setValue(bar->maximum());
}

void Console::setLocalEchoEnabled(bool set)
{
    localEchoEnabled = set;
}

void Console::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    switch (e->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Backspace:
    case Qt::Key_Left:
    case Qt::Key_Right:
    case Qt::Key_Up:
    case Qt::Key_Down:
        break;
    default:
        if (localEchoEnabled)
            QPlainTextEdit::keyPressEvent(e);
        emit getData(e->text().toLocal8Bit());
    }
}

void Console::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    Q_UNUSED(e)
    setFocus();
}

void Console::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    Q_UNUSED(e)
}

void Console::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *e)
{
    Q_UNUSED(e)
}
```

The Qt Example is this one:  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-terminal-example.html

Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you know how you would use, say, `QTextEdit` inside another widget? If not, then consider spending a bit of time learning Qt basics. I personally consider the [Address Book tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/tutorials-addressbook.html) to be very to-the-point and concise, showing how to assemble a UI and how to tie the components together. Even if you use Designer, you still need to know the stuff covered in this tutorial to understand what is going on in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to add it via designer just promote the QWidget that you added in your screegrab. (Right click > "Promote to..." > Fill in name & path to the console header).

Or not using promotion, you can add the console to a layout in code :

```
Console* console = new Console();
ui->your_layout_name_here->addWidget( console );
```